# scale background image in div depending on screen size

Tags: html, css, background-image, scale

I have a div containing a background image that I want to keep aligned in the bottom right corner but I want the image to scale depending on the size of the browser window. What I currently have is:

```
backgnd {
    background: url(img/roneggler.png) no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

I have tried to set the `width` and `height` values to `100%` but that messes with the position of the `div`. The link of this page can be found here: http://inetgate.biz/ron.eggler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I got it now, the final solution looks like:

```
.backgnd {
    background: url(img/roneggler.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: right bottom;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The trick was t use `background-size: contain;` instead of `cover` to not get the image to scale up all the way on big screens.

Answer (score 1):

You should use     background-size: cover and width and height 100%;

```
backgnd {
    background: url(img/roneggler.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If I use what you suggest, the image isn't bottom aligned.

Comment: Try using position aboslute  (instead of fixed )  ..and eventually set the proper bottom right position

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `absolute` as you suggested above. It looks like the div scales nicely but the background image doesn't stay aligned `absolute` to the bottom right corner of the div. I added a temporary `border: 5px solid red;` to the div to better depict things

Comment: you should post a link to jsfiddle for or codepen for see the page and the code ..

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.container{
  width:100%;
}
```

you can use jQuery:

```
var w = $(window).width();
$('.content').css('width', w);
```